# Switch from feature branch to master branch

Tags: git, git-bash

I am trying to switch from feature branch to master branch using the below command, but i am facing following issue. how can i switch back to master branch

Current branch shows in git bash:

```
feature/test
```

Command used:

```
git checkout master
```

Error:

```
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

Comment: Use `git branch -vva` to verify that you do have a `master` branch. From the error, it does not seem so.

Comment: @Amadan Or maybe `git checkout` was being run trailing some other incorrectly entered command.

Comment: When i run this git branch -vva command it does not throw neither throw any error nor display any list

Comment: This is strange. You should at least be showing `feature/test`, if it reports you're on it... How about `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`? Does it show `feature/test`?

Comment: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref, it does not show any (no error too). as well when i try git checkout test also am getting error message as error: pathspec 'feature/test' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Comment: Can you paste the output of `git branch -v`
This will list all the available branch.
If master branch  is not present you will need to add it back

Comment: @AjinkyaDhote git branch -v does not list any branches.

Comment: Seems you don't have any branches (not even remote ones). You will likely have to play with `git reflog` to find the commit that you'd call a branch, then `git branch branch_name commit_id` to re-label it.

Comment: @user2000189, the problem is no branch is present, hence `master` is not treated as a branch, but instead git is treating it as a file. Now you can understand the error.

To resolve, you will need to add a mster branch, to do so, you can do this,

`git remote add master <git-url>`
This will set the master branch to track the <git-url> you are intrested in

Comment: master and feature branches, i could able to see in BitBucket it is available ,but from local git bash when i try git branch -v it does not show any branches

Comment: hi, after you initializing git repo with git init, have you created the test branch using git checkout -b feature/test ? and if you do a "git branch", it does n`t show any other branches ? Or
have you cloned the remote repo?
have you done a "git fetch --all" ?

Answer (score 1):

message `error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git` will show when your target branch(`master`) does not exist.

I guess you don't have branch `master` on your local repository and your local repository does not update.

Please try `git branch -a` to show all branches on your repository.

If you're not found branches `master` or `remote/origin/master` please try `git remote update` to fetch data from centralize repository and use `git branch -a` again. if branch `master` or `remote/origin/master` is present you can check out them now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to fetch in order to update your `origin` folder.
Try `git fetch` and you should find master pretty easily.